# AES-128 (WOWZA) in PHP. How to do this?

Tags: php, encryption, aes, wowza, http-live-streaming

I'm using Wowza Streaming Engine and I want to encrypt mp4 files in HLS streaming method but I don't know how to create AES-128 keys in PHP?

Wowza has its own genkey but it's in java and have to be done in SSH. I want  to do this in PHP but I don't know how it creates key? Informations about generating keys are here - https://www.wowza.com/docs/how-to-secure-apple-http-live-streaming-aes-128-external-method

Can you tell me how to generate keys like this in PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key can be anything you want as long as it's 16-bytes (128 bits) and formatted as a hexadecimal string:

`$key = strtoupper(bin2hex(random_bytes(16)));`

Comment: Thanks, it was the simplest good answer :)

Answer (score 3):

I assume that you have wowza configured and can stream not encrypted stream.

Key is shared for all clients that are streaming it. You don't need to generate it in any way. Tool from that article is just a utility that will create random key and prepare file. But you can do that by hand.

To encrypt it - but only for ios devices! - do the following:

1. in wowza dir there should be sub-directory keys, create it if needed.
2. for each endpoint that will stream create file named: `<my_endpoint_name>.key` In their example they use `myStream.key`.
3. Content of this file is simple:

`cupertinostreaming-aes128-key: secret
cupertinostreaming-aes128-url: <url for CLIENT device to get DECRYPTION key>, for example: http://example.com/key_service.php`

4. In the examples section of that page there is sample script that will output key in specific format using correct headers. Place this file under that url (in this example: `http://example.com/key_service.php`) and replace secret from there (`DE51A7254739C0EDF1DCE13BBB308FF0`) with your secret. You can pass additional parameters to this script (see below). This file will be called by client device automatically (Wowza will instruct client to fetch it) to get the key. It can be different domain and it can be one file for all your streams.
5. Any additional parameters passed to playlist file `(http://[wowza-ip-address]:1935/live/<my_endpoint_name>/playlist.m3u8`) will be passed to your key generating php script: you can pass user id or some other form of authentication/authorization and use that to generate validate user and only then to return key - remember that key must not be user dependent - it must be the same as in file in step 2.

And that's it. 
tl;dr: create key file with key and url from where that key will be returned. Create file at that url that will return that key.